# ClassFormatError in Twitter4J

Tags: java, exception, twitter4j

I have a program that updates a twitter account when somebody is connecting to the server. From wednesday till this morning the program worked fine. Now I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 133 in class file java/util/Arrays$ArrayList
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3355)
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.toParamList(OAuthAuthorization.java:371)
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.generateAuthorizationHeader(OAuthAuthorization.java:206)
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.generateAuthorizationHeader(OAuthAuthorization.java:260)
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getAuthorizationHeader(OAuthAuthorization.java:75)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.setHeaders(HttpClientImpl.java:246)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:116)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1764)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:447)
```

The program uses twitter4j for posting on twitter. I got the newest jar for twitter4j, released today and I have updated to the latest jvm, but I'm still having this problem.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You should recompile your code using the latest twitter api jar, most likely they have changed the interface to their apis and your code will need to be updated.